# Referencing Plugin Functions from Button Tap in Nativescript

Tags: plugins, nativescript

I have really confused myself with the logical flow of code in plugins. I am using this [seed](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-plugin-seed) and am trying to create a button in the demo app, which calls a function from the plugin which just contains a console.log, I have:

```
//yourPlugin.common.ts:
import * as app from 'application';
import * as dialogs from 'ui/dialogs';

export class Common {
  public message: string;

  constructor() {
    this.message = Utils.SUCCESS_MSG();
  }
}

export class Utils {
  //Utils Stuff - not relevant for this issue
}

 export function Click() {
      console.log("Clicked");
  }


//demo/app/main-view-model.ts:

import {Observable} from 'data/observable';
import {YourPlugin} from 'nativescript-yourplugin';

export class HelloWorldModel extends Observable {
  public message: string;
  private yourPlugin: YourPlugin;
  private Click: YourPlugin.Click;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.yourPlugin = new YourPlugin();
    this.message = this.yourPlugin.message;
  }
}
```

and then in my xml, I added `<Button text="This is Button!" tap="Click" />` to my app page. However, when I press the button, the console log isn't triggering, what have I got wrong?

Update:

xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="{{ message }}" class="message" textWrap="true"/>
    <Button text="This is Button!" tap="{{ Click }}" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.ts:

```
import * as observable from 'data/observable';
import * as pages from 'ui/page';
import {HelloWorldModel} from './main-view-model';

// Event handler for Page "loaded" event attached in main-page.xml
export function pageLoaded(args: observable.EventData) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = <pages.Page>args.object;
    page.bindingContext = new HelloWorldModel();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This syntax:

```
import {YourPlugin} from 'nativescript-yourplugin'
```

Imports only the class named `YourPlugin` from the `nativescript-yourplugin` module. So you do not have access to anything else in the `main-view-model.ts` file. In order to to have access to the other things defined in your plugin you must import the whole module. Also in your `HelloWorldModel` the `Click` should be a function and you only define it as some type. And more over the `Click` function is not public. So your code should look something like:

```
import {Observable} from 'data/observable';
import nsPlugin = require('nativescript-yourplugin');

export class HelloWorldModel extends Observable {
  public message: string;
  private yourPlugin: nsPlugin.YourPlugin;

  public Click = nsPlugin.Click;

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.yourPlugin = new nsPlugin.YourPlugin();
    this.message = this.yourPlugin.message;
  }
}
```

And finally assuming you are binding your XML to an instance of `HelloWorldModel` your button should look like this:

```
<Button text="This is Button!" tap="{{ Click }}" />
```

Comment: If I copy your exact code, + import the plugin as `import * as nsPlugin from 'nativescript-yourplugin';`  I still don't get a console.log on button press ...